# Play Framework: How to get field names from Json

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

Given the following JSON...

```
{
  "fieldOne": "valueOne",
  "fieldTwo": "valueTwo"
}
```

... how do I get field names `fieldOne` and `fieldTwo` with the Play JSON library (Scala version)? I need this because in my use case field names may change depending on the context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you have a `JsObject`, you can call `keys`:

```
val js = Json.parse("""{
  "fieldOne": "valueOne",
  "fieldTwo": "valueTwo"
}""")

js.transform[JsObject].map(_.keys)
```

With that you get a `JsResult[Set[String]]` and you can decide how to deal with error handling.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't seem to work with play Json 2.4.2. I get a compiler error: "missing arguments for method transform in trait JsReadable"

Answer (score 4):

In Play Json 2.4.3, at least, your syntax is a bit different:

```scala
val js = Json.parse("""{
  "fieldOne": "valueOne",
  "fieldTwo": "valueTwo"
}""")

js.as[JsObject].fields
//or
js.as[JsObject].fieldSet
```